How do I fetch a post by ID without API and stop calling the API every time I navigate back to it?
Stack

Svelte
@tanstack/svelte-query

Setup
I have two different pages (HTML omitted):

posts/+page.svelte
post/[id]/[title]/+page.svelte

I use TanStack Query for storing data from the API. While I reference Svelte, I also use the documentation for React.js as most syntax seems to be compatible.
Here are the two major problems I am facing:

In the posts page, I fetch all posts as an array. It fetches all data, but every time I navigate to this page, an API call is fired. I don't want to make redundant API calls. How can I prevent this behavior?

In the [id]/[title]/ page, I want to fetch post data from the already fetched data from the API, but the post is undefined. This problem is more serious. How can I log post from cached data?


Here is the simplified code for the two files:
src/routes/posts/+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { createQuery } from "@tanstack/svelte-query";
  import type { Post } from "$lib/models/Post";
  import { fetchPaginatedPosts } from "$lib/posts/fetch-pagination";
  import { data } from './store';

  // Create the query outside of the render context
  const query = createQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: fetchPaginatedPosts,
    initialData: null,
    refetchInterval: 360000, // Using the intervalMs from the store if needed
  });

  // Subscribe to the data store and update it with the query result
  onMount(() => {
    data.set($query);
  });

  let posts: Post[] = [];

  $: $data = $data || $query.data;

  $: {
    if ($data && !$data.isLoading && !$data.isError && $data.data) {
      posts = $data.data.posts || [];
      console.log("call without API", posts);
    }
  }
</script>

src/routes/post/[id]/[title]/+page.svelte
  <script lang="ts">
  import { page } from "$app/stores";
    import type { Post } from "$lib/models/Post";
    import { QueryCache } from "@tanstack/svelte-query";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
  
    const queryCache = new QueryCache()
  
  const query = queryCache.find({ queryKey: ['posts']})
  
  let posts: Post[]
  let post: Post
  $: id = $page.params.id;

  onMount(()=>{
    posts = $query.data.posts
    post = posts.find(post.id === id)
  })
  onMount(()=>{
    console.log(post)
  })
  </script>


After getting answer:
src/hooks.server.ts
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { fetchPaginatedPosts } from '$lib/posts/fetch-pagination';
import { queryClient } from '$lib/posts/queryClient'; // Assuming you have a separate queryClient instance
import { fetchedPosts } from '$lib/posts/store';
import type { Posts } from '$lib/models/Post';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/posts')) {

    const cachedData = queryClient.getQueryData(['posts']);

    if (!cachedData) {
      const posts = await fetchPaginatedPosts();
      queryClient.setQueryData(['posts'], posts);
        fetchedPosts.set(posts)

    }else{
        fetchedPosts.set(cachedData as unknown as Posts)
  
    }
    
  }


  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
};


You can use sveltes Middleware (hooks.server.ts). In the middleware get the data you need, and check if the correct data was retrieved for the page if not run it again.

This will solve:
You need to add: queries: {enabled: browser}
src/routes/+layout.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { browser } from '$app/environment'
  import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/svelte-query'
  // add css import if you need
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        enabled: browser, // this line
      },
    },
  })
</script>

<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <slot />
</QueryClientProvider>

